# Is it possible to start hive standalone metastore with just hadoop commons?

Tags: hadoop, apache-hive

I'm trying to launch my own hive standalone metastore `v3.0.0` in a kubernetes env, and write into postgresql as the backend database.

But through my experience so far, I need to have hadoop binaries present in the image itself in order to `schematool -initSchema` and `start-metastore`.

The question i have is, hadoop is about 700mb big, which unpacks into 1.4gb. And because I'm only using hive standalone metastore, is it possible to use a reduced hadoop binary to support this? If yes, how should it be done?